# Register Node Module Manually

Tags: node.js, typescript, module, ts-node

## Question:

I have a project in TypeScript that uses several APIs I don't have access to on my computer (they exist on the web). The code will compile fine locally since I have all the APIs in `foo.d.ts` files, and so the system knows they exist somewhere.

However, I want to unit test parts of the code with a NodeJS app. I can import the code into node just fine, but whenever I reach code that imports a module from a definition file, I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'messages'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:527:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:476:23)
    at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (~/dev/repos/sample_typescript_fail/App.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
...
```

This makes sense, since that code is just defined locally, and does not exist.

**Can I manually register modules to NodeJS, like**

```
 Registry.register('messages', () => {...});
```

**so that I can compile and test with polyfills?**

---

## Here's an example app

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "sample_typescript_declare_issue",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node index.ts"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

`index.ts`

```
import {App} from "./App";

console.log("Starting program");

// How do I fake "import {MessageSender} from "messages";"
// here so that I can run this node app as a test?

let app: App = new App();

console.log("Ending program");
```

`App.ts`

```
import {MessageSender} from "messages";

export class App {
    constructor() {
        let messageSender: MessageSender = new MessageSender();
        messageSender.sendMessage("foo!");
    }
}
```

`node_modules/@types/messages/index.d.ts`

```
export = Messages;
export as namespace Messages;

declare module Messages {

    class MessageSender {
        constructor();
        sendMessage(message: any): void;
    }

}
```

---

## Running Example App

Running with `npm start` gives the error message above.

Running `tsc *.tsc` compiles just fine.

---

## Other things I've tried

1. Updating package.json to include a bin:

   ```
   {
     "name": "sample_typescript_declare_issue",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "description": "",
     "main": "index.ts",
     "scripts": {
       "start": "ts-node index.ts"
     },
     "author": "",
     "license": "MIT",
     "bin": {
       "messages": "./polyfills/messages/index.ts"
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, compiling works fine - this is just a question of availability of `.d.ts` files.

What you want to do is alter module import at runtime, in other words alter the behaviour of the nodejs `require` function since

```
import {MessageSender} from "messages";
```

will be transpiled in javascript (ES6) to something like

```
const messages_1 = require("messages");
...
messages_1.MessageSender
```

To modify that behaviour, the first thing that springs to mind is to use the **deprecated** - but still available -  [`require.extensions`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require) object.

When running locally you must first inject something like

```
require.extensions['.js'] = (module, filename) => {
    if (filename === 'messages') {
        // then load mock module/polyfill using the passed module object
        // see (https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_object)
    }
};
```

The doc says there are better alternatives but fails to clearly mention any.

Another possibility is to look at projects like [sandboxed-module](https://github.com/felixge/node-sandboxed-module) which should help (I have not tested it)

Comment: I tried both solutions, but neither seems to work. The extensions wouldn't allow me to call "super", and the sandboxed module never worked for me. It didn't inject anything.